# How to view photos attached In Telegram chats

Tags: ubuntu-touch, telegram

I have telegram on my Ubuntu tablet and my android phone. On the phone when I get a photo attached in a chat, I just click on it and it opens in a big window for viewing. However, when I do the same in my tablet, clicking on the photo does not open it in a big window.

How can I set telegram up in my tablet, to open a photo attached in a chat window into a big window for viewing?

Comment: Which Telegram client are you using (there is > 1 available)?

Comment: Telegram for Ubuntu 2.2.30(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the latest update, this issue has now gone away. i can only assume that it has been fixed in the latest version. I can not click on the photos that I have in a chat window and they open in full screen correctly.